# Web API POST Request adding a new record, however all attributes are set to NULL?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API POST Request that should add a new record to a specific table using the attributes found within the body as JSON. However, when entering all the attributes (which I assume to be correct), the request will end up adding a new record, however ALL the attributes will be set to NULL for whatever reason?

Below is my API Post Request:

```
/*Define URL endpoint for adding a single role*/
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Roles/addRole")]
        /*HttpPost header, ensures only the usage of POST requests*/
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        /*Main return new list with added role*/
        public List<dynamic> addRole([FromBody] Roles roles)
        {
            if (roles != null)
            {
                /*Create an instance of the UltimateDB*/
                UltimateDBEntities db = new UltimateDBEntities();
                /*Optimize memory usage by disabling proxy creation*/
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                db.Roles.Add(roles);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return getAllRoles();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

The above should add a single record to the "Roles" table, using the data from the body (JSON) entered by the user. I have tested this using Postman, and all that is returned is a new record with all of its attributes set to NULL.

For example, I will enter this:

```json
{
    "Name": "Lab Employee",
    "Description": "User only has read rights",
    "Tenant_rental": 1,
    "Property_Module": 0,
    "Employee_Management": 0,
    "Reports": 1,
    "administration": 1,
    "user_Password_access": 0,
    "Building_Management": 0,
    "Credit_Bureau": 1
}
```

And get this as my new record:

```json
{
        "ID": 23,
        "Name": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Tenant_rental": null,
        "Property_Module": null,
        "Employee_Management": null,
        "Reports": null,
        "administration": null,
        "user_Password_access": null,
        "Building_Management": null,
        "Credit_Bureau": null
    }
```

My Roles Class:

```
namespace U18043039_HW1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Roles
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Roles()
        {
            this.User_Table = new HashSet<User_Table>();
        }
    
        public int Role_ID { get; set; }
        public string Role_Name { get; set; }
        public string Role_Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Tenant_rental { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Property_Module { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Employee_Management { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Reports { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_administration { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_user_Password_access { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Building_Management { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Role_Credit_Bureau { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<User_Table> User_Table { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your Roles class pls?

Comment: @Sergey I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this data for test:

```
{
    "Role_Name": "Lab Employee",
    "Role_Description": "User only has read rights",
    "Role_Tenant_rental": True,
    "Role_Property_Module":False,
    ... and so on
}
```

Comment: This change restricts me from returning getAllRoles - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable<U18043039_HW1.Models.Roles>' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: I now get:  System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[U18043039_HW1.Models.Roles]'.'

Comment: It doesn' t matter , keep the previous one as well

Comment: Okay this was my problem. thank you so much